# Firebase push notification with custom sound (Flutter)

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm currently using firebase messaging cloud to push notification for my app. I'm trying to make a custom notification sound for the push notification. I believe that it can be done by putting "sound: blabla.mp3" inside the payload, but how do i define the sound inside dart page?

Answer (score 1):

Use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package

```
AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationsDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
       'your other channel id',
       'your other channel name',
       'your other channel description',
        importance: Importance.Max,
        priority: Priority.Max,
        enableLights: true,
        playSound: true,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),
);
```

Note: you should add notification.mp3 file in android/app/src/main/res/raw/notification.mp3 and don't forget to specify playSound:

```
playSound: true,
```

this worked for me in the foreground / background and when the app is closed.

Comment: I didn't try it on IOS yet.

Comment: it doesn't work with ios

Comment: Hi i have an issue that my sound is not playing, either when the apps is open or on the background

Answer (score 1):

It can be done [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin.

First, you should define channels for both Android and iOS:

```
const androidPlatformChannel = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  'ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID',
  'Name',
  'Description',
  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
  importance: Importance.max,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification_sound'),
  playSound: true,
  priority: Priority.high,
  showWhen: false,
);

const iOSPlatformChannel = IOSNotificationDetails(
  sound: 'notification_sound.aiff',
  presentAlert: true,
  presentBadge: true,
  presentSound: true,
);

const platformChannel = NotificationDetails(
  android: androidPlatformChannel,
  iOS: iOSPlatformChannel,
);
```

Then show a notification:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      platformChannel,
      payload: notification.payload,
    );
```

**IMPORTANT!** notification_sound.aiff file should be copied with XCode

Comment: That is for foreground notifications, will that work for background when app killed?

Comment: it was not working in the background

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply by calling the sound and playing it in the firebase configure method.

```
widget._firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on message $message');



    AudioCache player = new AudioCache();
    const alarmAudioPath = "sounds/notification.mp3";
    player.play(alarmAudioPath);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on resume $message');
  },
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print('on launch $message');
  },
);
```

this wouldnt be effective as the file wouldnt be played if the app is in the background

Comment: that's the problem, i want the notification sound to become custom sound

Comment: you achieve this simply by putting your custom sound in the android native section of your app, by default firebase would call it . plus i dont think u need to put .mp3 in the blabla.mp3 .. lemme check up the article for u

Comment: try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification . read up the sound option

Comment: there might be problem with api, because after nougat, the sound will not work, but thank you for the link though

Comment: i'm using android oreo before this, but when i use my old nexus 5 with android M, it works

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom notification sound for both Android you will need to predefine a Notification Channel for your app. I used [Flutter Local Notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) plugin to do this. In there, you can specify the parameters for your Android Notification Channel such as

`var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  'your other channel id',
  'your other channel name',
  'your other channel description',
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('slow_spring_board');`

Note: slow_spring_board.mp3 is stored in the `android\app\src\main\res\raw` section of your app. Do not include the file extension when calling `RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound()`

There are other steps required to get it setup for iOS devices (mp3 are not supported). Once this is all done, you can begin working on your cloud messaging portion, in there you'll have to reference the notification channel id, and the sound file. I recommend including the audio file extension in that code.

Comment: Hi @fpsColton, I am also facing the same issue. I have created channel in flutter code. Still custom sound is not playing. Do you have any suggestion?  See below: \n  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.max,
      enableVibration: true,
      playSound: true,
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('lfid_emergency'));

Comment: @Hiren, you should try defining a AndroidNotificationDetails object beforehand (including the channelAction: AndroidNotificationChannelAction.CreateIfNotExists field), and then passing that to your NotificationDetails object, which is used as a parameter for flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show() function.

Comment: what about IOS please? any help?

Comment: What are the other steps required to get it set up for iOS devices, please?

Comment: Store the audio file in .wav format, add it to your project in Xcode at the top of the project (mine is located in PROJECT_DIR/ios/alert.wav). Then target the sound file when sending a notification. Ex: 
apns: {
                    payload: {
                        aps: {
                            sound: 'alert.wav'}}}

Comment: I have tried all this above but still not working in the background

Answer (score 0):

```
You must create notification channel first with following code

Application.kt

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.Build.VERSION
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
import android.net.Uri;
import android.media.AudioAttributes;
import android.content.ContentResolver;

class Application : FlutterApplication(), PluginRegistrantCallback {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        this.createChannel()
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this)
    }

    override fun registerWith(registry: PluginRegistry?) {
//        createChannel();
        FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }

    private fun createChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // Create the NotificationChannel
            val name: String = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
            val channel = NotificationChannel(name, "default", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            val soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://"+ getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/raw/sample");
            val att = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
                    .build();
            channel.setSound(soundUri, att)

            val notificationManager: NotificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)

            /*
            val id = mapData["id"]
            val name = mapData["name"]
            val descriptionText = mapData["description"]
            val sound = "sample"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)
            mChannel.description = descriptionText





            // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
            // or other notification behaviors after this
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
            completed = true
             */
        }
    }
}

And android manifest.xml

    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.foodlz.orders">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
    <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:label="test App"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">




        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>


        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_appstore" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </application>


</manifest>


finally you must put your notification sound.wav file in res/raw

that's it
```

Comment: Any idea about iOS?