# Custom notification in flutter with firebase_messaging (Android and IOS)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

I am stuck on custom fcm push notification in flutter.

**Achieved**

I am able to send notification in my app form firebase console with help of firebase_messaging example code on `pub.dev`

**Want To Build**

I want to add some custom data in notification just like -

`custom sound,
custom title,
custom big text,
custom icon`

that's all thing want to add in my notification.

I am also able to fully customized notification in android but I want that on my flutter app.

Friends for friends
Thank You .

Comment: You can check this out [Firebase push notification with custom sound (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999804/5326843)

Comment: @SurajitMondal Did you try this? because it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

this flutter package still in development but still helps resolve and solve many troubles with customizing push notifications for android and ios:
https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications