# How to enable notification sound for flutter app using firebase notification?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-notifications

I am building a flutter application with firebase notification. But, I need a custom sound for notification. I had implemented `playSound: true, sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('notification'),` under AndroidNotificationDetails and copied the mp3 file to the raw folder in the proper location, but no use. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Add this sound key in your notification payload

```
{
    "to" : "AsS23rH5543:CI2k_AsS23rH5543CIZvvDMAsS23rH5543P1...",

    "notification" : {
      "body" : "your body",
      "title" : "Your Title",
      "icon" : "your icon",
      "sound" : "default"
    }
  }
```

If you need more help refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53531387/11789675)