# How to add custom notification sound for firebase push notification - Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently using firebase push notifications for notifications. I need to customize the default  sound.

I tried by "sound": "alert.mp3", instead of "sound": "default", but the sound I have given didn't trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase push notification with custom sound (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531387/firebase-push-notification-with-custom-sound-flutter)

Answer (score 2):

check out the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54003722/12037101) to know how to specify a custom sound for both android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

For this, you have two approaches. Both approaches require that you have a file with any name ("notification.wav" for this example) in your assets folder and that you have declared this file/folder in your pubspec.yaml file.

Approach 1 :
First, open the android part of the project in Android Studio and create a raw resource that specifies "notification.wav" as a resource. Then, when specifying AndroidNotificationDetails for firebase notifications, declare the 'playsound' and 'sound' parameter as follows :

```
AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  "notification_id",
  "notification channel name",
  channelDescription: "notification channel description",
  icon: "@mipmap/ic_launcher",
  playSound: true,
  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound("notification.wav"),
  actions: [
    accept_button,
  ]
);
```

The 'sound' parameter must be sent from backend in case of background notifications.

Approach 2 :
This approach uses the AudioPlayer class to play the asset audio when the notification is shown. This is implemented as a media audio rather than as a notification audio, so it will depend on the media volume of the device. I'll provide a sample that rings only when the phone is not in silent or vibrate, and forces the media volume to be maxed out using the [volume_controller](https://pub.dev/packages/volume_controller) plugin.

```
void audio_player_start() async {
  var ringer_mode = await SoundMode.ringerModeStatus;
  if(ringer_mode.name=="normal") {
    VolumeController().maxVolume(showSystemUI: false);
    AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer(playerId: "customNotificationPlayer");
    await player.setVolume(1.0);
    player.play(AssetSource(Paths().MUSIC_FOLDER+"notification.wav"));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    await player.stop();
    await player.release();
    await player.dispose();
  }
}
```

This function can be declared inside the FireBase class to use for foreground notification, but to use in the background, it must either be defined outside the class as a root function with the @pragma tag, or the content code must be used within the background handler function that's declared with the @pragma tag. If you wish to stop this alert when the notification is clicked instead of running for entire 5 seconds, you can assign the audio player to a global variable and then user the global variable to stop, release and dispose the player when notification is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

## Custom notification in Flutter

### Android setup

Firstly create an extra notification channel with

```dart
  // channel for default notifications
  const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'wave_remote_notifications', // id
      'Wave messages and updates', // title
      description: 'Primary channel for notifications and messages in wave app',
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
   
   // channel for custom sound  
   const AndroidNotificationChannel channelAudio = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'wave_remote_notifications_priority', // id
      'Wave messages and updates on priority', // title
      description: 'Primary channel for notifications and messages in wave app',
      sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('mario'),
      importance: Importance.max,
    );
    
    
    // if you use flutter_local_notification 
    
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channelAudio);
```

you can see we have added  `RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('mario')`

Now add mp3/wav file into **res/raw/yourmp3files.mp3**

now notification will work but only for debug mode as this file you added will not be included in release mode

So after that you need to add keep.xml inside `res/raw/keep.xml` to include yourmp3files.mp3 into build [keep.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlhMZ.png)

```dart
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/yourmp3files"
    />
```

### iOS setup

You have to add the sound into XCode. You can just drag and drop the audio file (in .caf or .wav supported format ) into the root directory (usually called Runner for Flutter) in XCode

That's all

### FCM Payload

final step

```dart
{
    "to": "f31vmSf8Qy2N57_33C9cf3:APA91bHBaz7yyRrKQTr_25mLNK2OVlBjdMqM8ux8kQwaeQcsXE6XnOhio7Tp5-CABTFTSbV1vBqqfIVj9Qd9eUdqNi9oojq8FdOWI-l1CU9Xw16-Xb4ZHVTycOM7nIRudIAmMkU6fjbm",
    // "collapse_key": "type_a",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "New visitor request",
        "body": "Answer to accept",
        "sound": "mario.wav",
        "android_channel_id": "wave_remote_notifications_priority"
    },
    "data": {
        "title": "New visitor request",
        "body": "Answer to accept ",
        "sound": "mario",
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "mutable-content": 1,
                "content-available": 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All set now all should work

Comment: This is working on my Android 14 but not on my Android 12, the notification is showing but the sound is not playing. Any ideas?